# JasperReports: How to mask or filter the labels at the chart's axis

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jfreechart

I´m using a simple area chart based on a simple Dataset like this:

```
DateTime(sql.timestamp) |Value(Integer)
2012-02-17 00:02:02     |100
2012-02-17 00:02:08     |110
2012-02-17 00:02:20     |90
2012-02-17 00:02:35     |10
2012-02-17 00:02:40     |130
2012-02-17 00:04:22     |14
2012-02-17 00:04:33     |45
2012-02-17 00:05:02     |60
...
```

DateTime is used by Category Axis, Value is used by Range Axis.
In the Dataset are ~1000 Records
In the Labels of the Category Axis will every DateTime Value be shown.
But that is with 1000 records too much, the Category Labels will be shown as Black Line.
And that is my problem.
I´d tried to (un)check all "Chart Properties". With no results.
Did i have to Mask or filter the labels?
I´d tried to change the values of:
**Category Tick Label Mask**
**Category Axis Vertical Tick Labels**
*(This checkbox doesn´t takes effect)*
**Label Expression of the Category Axis**
All in Several ways.
But it won´t work.
Each dataset will create an own Label.

Other report engines that i have used has calculated the Cat. Axis dynamic.
But JasperReports?

I´m using `iReport 4.5.0` with (actual) `jfreechart 1.0.14`

**EDIT**

If i use a timeseries Chart, JasperReports will group the data by Intervall (Year, month,...) and that not Dynamicly

But the look of the chart is quite good, so it is that what i want.
Only the Labels has to be located far from each other.

Here a fine Example (advsoft phpChartdirector)
[image: that is OK]

Here the JasperReports / IReport example:

not OK. Take a look to the cat. Axis

[image: not OK. Take a look to the cat. Axis]

So.. What´s to do ?

**End EDIT**

Kind Regards
Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Timeseries chart instead of a Line chart. You should get exactly what you're looking for that way.

EDIT: I tested with your supplied .jrxml and data. It works well:
[image: Nice Time Series Chart]

But... there seems to be a bug in iReport. You cannot set the time period in the iReport GUI. Perhaps this is what is causing you problems. It was very confusing to me. iReport generates this regardless of what time period you attempt to choose:

```
<timeSeriesDataset>
```

But you need to manually change the JRXML to this:

```
<timeSeriesDataset timePeriod="Second">
```

Once you do that, then you'll get a nice chart. At least iReport doesn't remove the correct timePeriod info... so you only have to do it once.

Note: If you're concerned about details like getting your date info to display on 2 lines, this is possible as well. I hate being stuck with a single line. I wrote an article about that last year. Look for the section [Category Labels on multiple lines](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/chart-customizers-2/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that is not that what i wan´t. Can you please take a look to my Edits at the End of my posting

Comment: You really need a Timeseries chart for this. A line chart can only make sense as a workaround and only if every time is exactly equally spaced. And that clearly doesn't apply to your data. Please post the .jrxml to see of that can help. You would probably need to post some sample data for someone to really take a look.

Comment: The "time period" can certainly be set in the iReport GUI: just go to "chart data", then "Details" to see the series you have plotted. There is a drop-down at the top of the dialog sheet for "Time period" which lets you set it appropriately.

Comment: The question specifies that he was using iReport 4.5 (the current version at that time). My answer doesn't re-specify this. But it's important. The GUI has not changed between 4.5 and 5.0 (the current version now). But in iReport 4.5 the choice of "Time period" did not get written into the .jrxml. Now it does. The workaround of editing the XML manually is no longer needed. Woo hoo!