# How to set max label lines for Date Ticks in JFreeChart Timeseries plots

Tags: java, jfreechart, time-series

I know how to create a CategoryPlot and then set the DomainAxis labels to use two lines. This is the idea:

```
CategoryAxis categoryAxis = categoryPlot.getDomainAxis();
categoryAxis.setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(2); // Mmmm... nice labels
```

But I'm having trouble doing "the same thing" for a Timeseries chart. The problem is that the DateAxis is a ValueAxis rather than a CategoryAxis. That makes sense because the dates are values. But I don't like the look of the chart when it uses only a single line for the date. You can see a sample chart in my answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325801/jasperreports-how-to-mask-or-filter-the-labels-at-the-charts-axis/9334004). I want to format my dates to use 2 lines. But I cannot do it like this:

```
DateAxis dateAxis = (DateAxis)xyPlot.getDomainAxis();
dateAxis.setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(2); // method does not exist
```

How can I get those Date labels onto 2 lines?

Answer (score 1):

Using `setVerticalTickLabels()`, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513), may alleviate the horizontal crowding; using `setDateFormatOverride()` may mitigate the resulting vertical space cost.

Comment: Yuck. And by "Yuck", I mean: I tested and it works like you suggested. Thanks. But vertical text will make it very hard to show data and time info. I need to stick with horizontal text. I'll just use `setDateFormatOverride` unless someone can offer a way of breaking the label onto 2 lines.

Comment: I guess you could use a sparser `TickUnit` and reveal the detail in a tooltip, for example.